# How to create directories according to filename and copy that file to the end of the directory using bash scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, video, youtube

Say I have a video file downloaded from YouTube called `some-user-uploader-how-to-do-something-playlist-video-1.mp4`, where `some-user` is the uploader's name, `how-to-do-something` is the playlist's name, and `video-1` is the video's name. Now, I want to write a bash script that copies the file from its present directory to a directory like `/uploader/playlist/`. I know this might be fairly easy for some, but I'm really new to scripting. So far, I've written this.

```
#script to copy a file named some-user-uploader-how-to-do-something-
#playlist-video-1.mp4 to /where/to/copy/uploader/playlist
#!/bin/bash

#set the path of the files to FILES 

FILES=*

#goes through all the files one by one and initialize them to f
for f in $FILES
do
    #I have no idea what happens here. I wanted to check if a file has
    #"-playlist" in it's name
    if [[ !($f == ${f%%-playlist*}) ]]
    then
    #set the uploader's name to uploader
    uploader="${f%%-uploader*}"
    #set the playlist's name to playlist
    playlist="${f%%-playlist*}"
        #checks if the destination directory exists
        if [ -f "/where/to/copy/$uploader" ]
        then
            #if it exists prints the message "directory already exists"
            echo "directory already exists."
         else
            #if the directory doesn't exist it creates the directory to
            #name of the uploader 
            `mkdir /where/to/copy/$uploader`
        fi


        #checks if the destination directory exists
        if [ -f "/where/to/copy/$uploader/$playlist" ]
        then
            #if it exists prints the message "directory already exists"
            echo "file already exists."
        else
             #if the directory doesn't exist it creates the directory to
             #name of the playlist
            `mkdir /where/to/copy/$uploader/$playlist`
        fi
        #checks if the file exists in the destination directory
        if [ -f "/where/to/copy/$uploader/$playlist/$f" ]
        then
            #if it exists prints the message "file already exists"
            echo "file already exists."
        else
            #if the file doesn't exist in the destination directory it
            #copies the file to that directory
            `cp -r $f /where/to/copy/$uploader/$playlist/$f`
        fi
fi
done
```

It works fine but I have no idea why. If someone could please explain how it works or knows a better way to get the same result, please help.

**Changes I have made to my script. Hopefully this will help others who are looking for a script with similar functionality.**

```
#!/bin/bash

# script to move a file named some-user-uploader-how-to-do-something-
# playlist-video-1.mp4 to /where/to/copy/uploader/playlist/video-1.mp4

FILES="*"

DESTDIR=${1:-"/where/to/copy"} 

for f in $FILES
do
    if [[ ! ( "$f" == "${f%%-playlist*}" ) ]]
    then    
        uploader="${f%%-uploader*}"
        uploader_playlist="${f%%-playlist*}"
        playlist="${uploader_playlist#${uploader}-uploader-*}"
        filename="${f#${uploader_playlist}-playlist-*}"

        mkdir -p "$DESTDIR/$uploader/$playlist"

        mv -n "$f" "$DESTDIR/$uploader/$playlist/$filename"

    fi
done
```

Comment: First start by removing all backticks to avoid executing output as none of them are properly used, or needed, in your code.  In the lines you remove the backticks then double quote the variables appropriately.  Also put spaces between the parentheses in `if [[ !($f == ${f%%-playlist*}) ]]`,   e.g. `if [[ ! ( $f == ${f%%-playlist* } ) ]]`

Comment: I used the hashes to comment because I thought it would be easier for people to read. I'm new to this. I still don't understand why it has to be if [[ ! ( "$f" == "${f%%-playlist*}" ) ]] and not if [[ "$f" == "${f%%-playlist*}" ]]

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I didn't know what backticks are.

Comment: Ehm... do you really need all that output? If not why do not use `mkdir -p  "/where/to/copy/$uploader/$playlist"` (`-p`  no error if existing, make parent directories as needed) and   `cp -n "$f" "/where/to/copy/$uploader/$playlist/$f"`( `-n` do not overwrite an existing file) ? Quotes (`"`) are needed in case in the name there is at least a space...

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help.

Comment: @UndercoverLemon Try putting your scripts into this: http://www.shellcheck.net/  It can be pretty helpful.

Comment: just in case, to obtain _how-to-do-something_ you need to cut  `some-user-uploader-` too from your string (`echo "${playlist#${uploader}-uploader-*}"`).

Comment: I didn't mind that. But you've solved a problem I didn't have. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hastur Cool, thanks, man. I figured out how to make the file move to `/uploader/playlist/video-1.mp4` before the `filename` used to be the whole thing like `some-user-uploader-how-to-do-something-playlist-video-1.mp4` and now it's just `video-1.mp4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version that should works and some note below. Test it.
After a `chmod u+x Go.sh` you can call with `./Go.sh` and it will take the default one, or you can pass it another destination path e.g. `./Go.sh /media/UndercoverLemon/storage/definitive`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Comment from the second line the first is the shebang # [0]
FILES="*"
DESTDIR=${1:-"/media/UndercoverLemon/storage/test"}     # [1]
for f in $FILES
do
    if [[ ! ( "$f" == "${f%%-playlist*}" ) ]]           # [2]
     then    
        uploader="${f%%-uploader*}"                     # [3]
        playlist="${f%%-playlist*}"                     # [4]
        playlist="${playlist#${uploader}-uploader-*}"   # [5]
        mkdir -p  "$DESTDIR/$uploader/$playlist"        # [6] 
        cp -n "$f" "$DESTDIR/$uploader/$playlist/$f"    # [7]
    fi
done
```

Notes:

The [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Syntax) `#!/bin/bash` have to be the 1st line of the script.

1. Better here only 1 place
2. Here below you check if the string $f is equal to same the string cut before -playlist*.  If it is equal it means there was not the
   substring "-playlist" in $f. With the not `!` you negate the result of the test.
3. Here `uploader="some-user"`
4. Here `playlist="some-user-uploader-how-to-do-something"`. Now you need to  cut the part with the current user `$uploader` and the *keyword* `-uploader-`
5. Here playlist="how-to-do-something"
6. Now you can create the directory if needed. `mkdir -p full/path/to` will
   give no error if existing and will make parent directories as needed.
7. Now you can copy the file if needed. The option `-n` will say to `cp` *"do not overwrite an existing file"*.